How to represent x and y in terms of a and b?
For given, x an y and we get equations of a and b below:
m = 3*(x^2)/2*y
a = m^2 - 2*x
b = m*(x-a) - y 

How to do it reverse? How to represent x and y in terms of a and b? Is it really possible?
or
For given, x an y and we get equations of a and b below:
a = 9(x^4)/4(y^2) - 2x
b = 3(x^3)/2y - [9(x^4)/4(y^2) - 2x]*(3*(x^2)/2*y) - y

How to do it reverse? How to represent x and y in terms of a and b ?

But $x=(m^2-a)/2$ is already in terms of $a,m$. Hence $y=(x-a)-b$ is given in terms of $a,b,m$.

sorry, it would be - How to represent x and y in terms of a and b? because m is already in terms of x and y

When you write m = 3*(x^2)/2y do you mean m = 3(x^2)/(2*y) ?

For given, x an y and we get equations of a and b below:
a = 9(x^4)/4(y^2) - 2x
b = 3(x^3)/2y - [9(x^4)/4(y^2) - 2x](3(x^2)/2*y) - y
How to do it reverse? How to represent x and y in terms of a and b ?

Is there any way to represent x and y in terms of a and b purely?

Yes, it is possible. Because you can write $m$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ alone.

How? m is coming which is related to x and y

No, the first equation relates $m$ with $a,b$ by $m^4-6am^2-8bm-3a^2=0$. Substitute $x,y$ as below in the first equation to obtain this equation.

How have you gotten this equation m4−6am2−8bm−3a2=0

As I said, I have substituted $x=(m^2-a)/2$ and so on.

you are great! But what will be the root value of m?

The last two equations give
\begin{align*}
x & = \frac{1}{2}(m^2-a),\\
y & = m(x-a)-b=\frac{1}{2}( m^3- 3am - 2b).
\end{align*}
Here we can express $m$ by $a$ and $b$, since we have the first equation, which gives after substitution of $x$ and $y$, that
$$
m^4-6am^2-8bm-3a^2=0.
$$
So we can express $x,y$ by only $a$ and $b$. The formula for the roots of the quartic equation in $m$ is not really nice, though.

But what will be the root value of m?

you are great!  How have u got this solution now?

See wikipedia.

Please do not delete that equation

You can use the formulas from wikipedia, or use a computer.

+-s  and +-t is making me confused
